# how should I make other people's configuration files and plugins for vim work for my own?

Tags: vim

I am now learning using vim. It seems that you can make vim an IDE for a programming language using a specific configuration file an plugins. How should I make other people's configuration files and plugins for vim work for my own?

Comment: Could you be more specific? What problems are you having?

Comment: Frobnicate, of course. Or use a frobnicator

Comment: @sehe — Since I moved to 7.3 my frobnicator stopped working. Maybe that's what happened to the OP. Do you know how to make it work with 7.3 or do I have — sigh — to revert to 7.2?

Comment: LOL @romainl: I had no such luck. Do you have any particular plugins that fail or specific lines in your config files that complain? I might help you fix those using a spare frobnicator I keep around for emergencies :)

Comment: @sehe — Thanks for the offer but — as you probably know — it's too hard to jump from one frobnicator to the other: the emotional rollercoaster I went through when switching to Linux is not something I want to live again. Frobnicators — and their masters — are so fragile. I've read somewhere that TextMate's Rhonfibulers where somehow similar. I might try it sometimes… after Roberta close her eye.

Comment: @sehe — Roberta is my frobnicator's name, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Frobnicators aside, here's my two cents:

You're asking about two different things. One is config files, and the other is plugins.

So, for **config files**, what works for me is an iterative approach. I just trawl the Web in search of interesting .vimrc files (I actually googled ".vimrc" a few times and come up with interesting results). Some of them are very well commented. When I see an interesting command or setting, I just try it out. If I like it, I tack it on to my own .vimrc, usually with the date and a comment explaining what it does.

For **plugins** it's obviously less iterative, because you just install and try to see if it works. What language would you like to use vim with?

Comment: As I am an absolutely vim beginner. I want to learn from demos of vim configuration files and plugins, like the package at https://github.com/panweizeng/env. What I am exactly asking is that how I can using the exited configurations and plugins.